# Psexec brute forcing credentials

Tags: brute-force, psexec, penetration-testing, metasploit

I am currently pen-testing with a Kali software installed machine and a Windows 8 installed Machine.

I am trying to gain access with a psexec_command attack with Metasploit.

Is there maybe a way that I could brute force the credentials for the psexec?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you use a wordlist or generator against -p parameter of psexec.exe after getting a username with wmic.exe or another tool. I don't know of a way to get users in Linux I'm sure there is a tool though. With Linux you can probably do a bruteforce tool in bash using pipes or something.

Comment: Note that even if 135,139, or 445 are open it doesn't mean psexec or other RPC methods will work. The target needs remote registry and shared running. 10 boxes typically have remote registry disabled.